# Zend framework: how to get user id form zend auth to zend form

Tags: forms, zend-framework, authentication, zend-form, zend-auth

I have a form comment. I want to get the user ID from `Zend_Auth` to insert into my database. How can I do it?

Answer (score 3):

If `Zend_Auth` has been instantiated, then:

1. Get an instance of it:
   `$auth = Zend_Auth::getInstance();`
2. Get the identity you must have stored on authentication success:
   `$identity = $auth->getIdentity();`
3. Use the identity according to the model of what you stored.